# Displaying custom query results in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm relatively new to Rails and in addition to displaying "All" items on my Index page, I also want to show a filtered list. Essentially a subset of records that have an association to another model.

My models are Issue and Split. A Split belongs to an issue and an issue has and belongs to many splits.

If a Split is associated with issue_id = 1, then I want it shown in the list of splits for that issue

Here is my controller code:

```
class SplitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_split, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /splits
  # GET /splits.json
  def index
    @splits = Split.all
    @chosen_splits = Issue.find(1)
  end
```

Here is the code I have in my index view:

```
<tbody>
  <% @chosen_splits.each do |split| %>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value></td>
      <td><%= link_to split.name, split_path(split) %></td>
      <td class="text-right"><%= number_with_delimiter(split.quantity) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_split_path(split), :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-default' %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', split, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Here is my Issue Model:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :publication
    has_and_belongs_to_many :splits
    has_many :issue_split_geographies
    belongs_to :medium

    validates :name, :start_date, :status, presence: true

end
```

When I load the page I'm getting a "undefined method `each' for" error. But, the same basic logic is working for when I run the @splits variable.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
@chosen_splits = Issue.find(1).splits
```

Otherwise you will call `.each` method for your issue

Else please edit `has_and_belongs_to_many :splits` to just `has_many :splits` in your `Issue` model

Comment: I did that, but now I'm getting this error: "PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "issues_splits" does not exist"